# How to do a Loop Until Condition in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

In my example I am working on a Google Sheets to help me calculate how much staff I'll need for a Call Center at particular times.

My equation for the cells highlighted in blue is `=1-(B40/30)`.  The numbers next to it (on the row for 8:30) were an experiment I did in which I say `=1-(B40/60)`, `=1-(B40/90)` and so forth etc.  The idea is that eventually it will equal 90% (0.90) or higher at some point.  **I need a way to loop and add 30 everytime like I did manually in my example** **and count how many times I had to do that until I reached the number 90%** (or whatever number I put for the highlighted green area in the picture).  For example it took 5 steps to get to 90%, so this function should return 5.

How do I do this? I have tried looking into array formulas but can't seem to figure out if this is the right method or not.

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot that shows rows and columns identifiers? It's a little hard to apply description to an image

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean? You can make up whatever numbers you want for them, I was just using those as an example.  I think this might be something where I have to make a custom function in scripts maybe?

Comment: It would be easier to work on tangible data, thats why I ask for this

Comment: If you want lets ignore what I put in my example, and just say I'm looking for a way to loop a function over and over until a condition and count how many times it looped.  I think this will make it easier to understand, my example is not important I made it up for this anyways.  For example lets say I want to say x=x+1 until x<7.  It will take 7 times before this happens so it returns 7.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, then... Look at the image:
[image]

And the code:

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(IF($C$4*TRANSPOSE(ROW($A$1:$A)*$C$3)/B9<$C$5,1,0)))+1
```

All variables are in C1:C5

Final formula is a bit complicated, so at the link below you will find step by step approach to this result (as a single formula)

[Link to working copy](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NVzv_A5_TOn1RpXpgTQQSTb1E0-lAQN1yTxMRfuVtDg/edit#gid=1820327850)

I hope it will help you

---

Edit:

If you want to simplify (based on your comment), look at this:

[image]

Code:

```
=SUM(ArrayFormula(IF($C$4*TRANSPOSE(ROW($A$1:$A))<B7,1,0)))+1
```